# Loop video back and forth in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, reverse, video-player

I am looking for a way to have a video played in a loop forth and back in iOS 7 and above.
This means, when the video ends, it starts from the end point and plays in reverse to the initial point. Then it plays again and so on.

I have already tried the `[videoPlayer setCurrentPlaybackRate:-1.0]` trick, but it doesn't do the job.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

could you use a for loop?

like

```
for (;;) //creates infinite loop
{
// your code
e.g. [videoPlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
}
```

or try this

```
[self performSelector: @selector(nameOfMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2]; [Ref][1]
```

Comment: or put it in an array by itself, or is there a numberOfLoops property like there is in audio?